# Mono.Cecil: call base class' method from other assembly

Tags: inheritance, assemblies, cil, il, mono.cecil

How can I get a MethodReference to a base class' method by name?

I've tried

```
type.BaseType.Resolve().Methods;
```

and if I add the dll containing the base class to the assemblyresolver it returns the methods.
But if I add a call using

```
MSILWorker.Create(OpCodes.Call, baseMethod);
```

(where baseMethod was found by foreaching Methods from the resolved TypeDefinition)
the resulting IL is unreadable, even Reflector freezes and quits.

Now some IL:
if calling private method on type:

```
 call instance void SomeNamespace.MyClass::RaisePropertyChanged(string)
```

if calling protected method on base type:

```
call instance void [OtherAssembly]BaseNamespace.BaseClass::RaisePropertyChanged(string)
```

So, how can I produce the latter using Mono.Cecil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you guessed, you need to get a proper MethodReference scoped for the module. So if you have:

```
TypeDefinition type = ...;
TypeDefintion baseType = type.BaseType.Resolve ();
MethodDefinition baseMethod = baseType.Methods.First (m => ...);
```

Then baseType and baseMethod are definitions from another module. You need to import a reference to the baseMethod before using it:

```
MethodReference baseMethodReference = type.Module.Import (baseMethod);
il.Emit (OpCodes.Call, baseMethodReference);
```

Comment: Can you please help me with my similar problem too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968755/mono-cecil-call-generic-base-class-method-from-other-assembly Thanks.

Comment: @TDaver: you should use the mono-cecil google group instead of SO, you'd have better chances of receiving answers quickly.