# Mono.Cecil get constructor for TypeReference

Tags: .net, mono, mono.cecil

I'm trying to create a `List<Simple>` using Mono.Cecil.  I have a `TypeReference` for this, but I'm not able to produce the correct results.

Given:

```
var listOfObjConstructor = this.ModuleDefinition.Import(listRef
    .Resolve().GetConstructors()
    .FirstOrDefault(c => (null == c.Parameters) || (0 >= c.Parameters.Count)));
```

`listOfObjConstructor` is

```
System.Void System.Collections.Generic.List`1::.ctor()
```

The IL I'm trying to produce is for

```
instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class AssemblyToProcess.Simple>::.ctor()
```

What do I need to do to create a new list object of the correct type?

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968755/mono-cecil-call-generic-base-class-method-from-other-assembly